# getSupportActionBar with YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am trying out youtube video to be played on my app. I understand this can be achieve by extending activity as YouTubeBaseActivity by doing this I don't have access to you my toolbar.

```
mActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mActionBar != null)
        {
            setSupportActionBar(mActionBar);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.youtubetitle));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I am getting getSupportActionbar could not be resolved. Is there an easy way to get access to toolbar by extending activity YouTubeBaseActivity.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tell me which type activity you want to extend ?appcompat activity ?

Comment: You can simply use a custom xml layout as header instead of actionbar.

Comment: Can you give me an idea?

Comment: I have updated my answer. please do check

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`YouTubeBaseActivity` extends `Activity`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeBaseActivity?hl=en), (as opposed to, for example `AppCompatActivity`), so the `getSupportActionBar()` method doesn't exist.

You could try to make your class extend `AppCompatActivity`, and use a [`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) instead wherever you would normally use a `YouTubePlayerView`.

**Edit:**

Add the following to your `layout` file, in place of a `YouTubePlayerView`

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Access it in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` in the same way you would any other static `Fragment`

```
public class CustomYouTubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitialisedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragments_demo);

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag =
            (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        frag.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
  boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
        //I assume the below String value is your video id
        player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Have you seen any sample Android App (Example) that can use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment - If so can you give me some link. I couldn't find any... as I don't know how to call them.

Comment: @SanjanaNair It's my understanding you would replace a `YouTubePlayerView` in your `layout` file with a static `Fragment`, and interact with it as you would any other static fragment. There are a few demos on [`GitHub`](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/tree/master/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo), and I've edited my answer above (untested).

Comment: Would you have to have a working build for this? I have something very similar, but the app crashes whenever I attempt to load a Youtube Support Fragment. I just asked a question regarding the AppCompatActivity with YTSupportFragment.

Comment: @krikara I could try and put a sample app together later tonight, but I wont be able to for a few hours yet. What's the link to your question?

Comment: @PPartisan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098897/appcompatactivity-crashing-with-embedded-youtube-videos

Thanks!

Comment: @PPartisan i have implemented your code, its working fine, thanks for your reference

Comment: you saved my life.

Comment: This works... Just Replace this fragment in your layout instead of Youtube Player View and its Done.. 
Thanks @PPartisan

Comment: That was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 1):

I was not interested in moving my already completed code to fragment for just adding a toolbar with a back button. So I figured out an easy way to do it.

Inside the layout xml I added a TextView which looks like a toolbar. Here's the code for the Textview. Also, you need to add a vector asset (back icon) in the drawable folder

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="56dp"
 android:id="@+id/actionbartitle"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:textSize="16sp"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:text="Go Back"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_8"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_back"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

And Simply adding onclicklistener on the textview for back press

```
val actionbarTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.actionbartitle)
 actionbarTitle.setOnClickListener {
           super.onBackPressed()
        }
```

Here's how the final result look likes! Have your cup of coffee :)

[image: Actionbar using Textview]