# AppCompatActivity crashing with embedded YouTube videos

Tags: android, youtube

For some reason, AppCompatActivity refuses to let me embed Youtube videos even though I am using the SupportFragment activity. The app crashes every time an activity contains a Youtube fragment. How can I fix this?

```
public class Insane1x1 extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBqaaaaaaa";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "3MvnRsItEmg"; //1-1

    //private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insane1x1);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide(); 

          youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.insane1x1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationFailure()", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {

        //youTubePlayer = player;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationSuccess()", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (!wasRestored) {
              player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            }

    }
```

And here's the xml file:

```
 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Is it the YouTubePlayer that is crashing the app, when it is cuing the video in the onInitializationSuccess method??

Comment: I've noticed there are quite a few different Youtube API Jar files floating around the internet. I'm currently using the latest one from the developer.google website.

Comment: I'd suggest including a logcat to make it easier for potential responders to figure out your issue

Comment: @FaizMalkani The app doesn't crash on my Bluestacks emulator, but it crashes on phones.

Comment: "The app doesn't crash on my Bluestacks emulator, but it crashes on phones" - What is the LogCat output when debugging on your phone?

Comment: @PPartisan I don't have an android phone to debug on unfortunately :( While it doesn't crash on Bluestacks, it certainly doesn't work as intended. The youtube video loads, plays 1 second, then stops.

Comment: I just put together a [sample project](https://github.com/PPartisan/SupportFragmentYouTubeDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/werdpressed/partisan/supportfragmentyoutubedemo/MainActivity.java) using code very similar to yours and everything works fine on an external device

Comment: @PPartisan so it turns out there were 2 major flaws. One had to something with my libraries and it wasn't building the project correctly. Your if frag null statement also fixed a lot. I'm still having another problem though. It seems like ScrollView in the xml is preventing my youtube video from loading properly in Bluestacks. It does work on other phones however.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cz its not extending "YouTubeBaseActivity", for some reason though YouTubeBaseActivity doesn't have as much functionality as AppCompatActivity. Maybe there are newer versions. But I'dd say thats the problem.