# Android YouTubePlayerView in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, youtube-api, deprecated, android-youtube-api

I'm implementing YouTube Android Player API and trying to add YouTubePlayerView to my AppCompatActivity accorting to [this manual](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), but get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
```

YouTubeBaseActivity extends Activity (not AppCompatActivity). I checked [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player) and noticed that the latest commit was 3 years ago, so I suppose that this library is deprecated especially given that it's distributed as .jar file only.
My question is next: where can I find source code of this library to fix YouTubeBaseActivity or what should I use instead of it? Or maybe you can suggest me better way to play YouTube video inside my app (without Intent)? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35584073/6236752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative would be to use `YouTubePlayerFragment`.

> A fragment that contains a YouTubePlayerView. Using this fragment is
>   the preferred way of playing YouTube videos because your activity does
>   not need to extend an activity provided by the library, as is the case
>   with using the YouTubePlayerView directly.

See if this helps you:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment

Comment: Thank you, it really works. I will add that it has YouTubePlayerSupportFragment (extends Fragment from support library) as well https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment