# setSupportActionBar not working on YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

I use YouTubeBaseActivity to extends myactivity but after that, setSupportActionBar not work again, how solution ? and i use androidx

this is my class

`public class DetailWisataActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements  YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`

in this case i want to show menu but not work and not show with `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: I haven't used the YouTube API since androidx, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584288) demonstrates how to use `AppCompatActivity` instead. However, from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment), it looks like `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` is still an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, so you probably wanna have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577000), too. I have no idea if the accepted answer there is valid.

Comment: i try this tomorrow to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584073/getsupportactionbar-with-youtubebaseactivity/35584288#35584288) but error, show error `migrate to androidx.fragment` i try this `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yt_player_view_detail);` and this `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yt_player_view_detail);` but still error

Comment: Yeah, that's why I linked to that other post, too. However, I meant to say "the unaccepted answer"; [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725269). The accepted answer makes no sense for the given error.

Comment: ok thanks for answer bro, now i have other solution, about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set below code in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.parent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Change to below code

```
<style name="AppTheme.parent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: anymore solution ? in this case, i have to use NoActionBar, this is my style `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Create custom toolbar and set in appbar layout

Comment: ok thanks for answer bro, now i have other solution, about my problem.