# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id) returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a basic app with fragments. My activity_main.xml has a

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

and in one of my fragments .xml files I have a

```
<fragment
            android:tag="youtube_tag"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
```

which I want to initialize. I am doing that from my MainActivity.java. My onCreate function:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...some other code...
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new RadioFragment()).commit();
        ...some other code...
        initializeYoutubePlayer();
        ....some other code....
    }
```

where `initializeYoutubePlayer();` is:

```
youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
....some other code...
```

and RadioFragment is the desired fragment's java file and it's content is:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio, container, false);
    }
```

the line in the `initializeYoutubePlayer();` returns a null pointer and than later in code I get the **NPE**.

Comment: Why is your Activity reaching into the layout of a Fragment at all? Shouldn't the fragment that adds the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` be the one interacting with it?

Comment: try to use below one

Comment: @ianhanniballake So you suggest that I move all the code related to the YTPF to the fragments Java file?

Comment: Or move the `<fragment>` into your Activity's layout directly. The whole point of a Fragment is to encapsulate a part of your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating static and dynamic fragments. The fragment you have defined in XML (with the `<fragment />` tag) isn't loaded through the `FragmentManager`, but is automatically created when your layout is inflated.

Replace your `FrameLayout` entirely with your `fragment` code, and access in with:

```
final YouTubeSupportFragment frag = (YouTubeSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.whatever_id_you_use);
frag.initalize(...);
```

**Edit:**
I've writen another answer on the YouTube fragment which has more detailed example code of how your Activity should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584073/getsupportactionbar-with-youtubebaseactivity/35584288#35584288)

**Edit 2:**

If `RadioFragment` has a layout which includes your YouTube fragment, then you should keep your Activity code as it is, and instead initialise your YouTube fragment inside RadioFragment. You may need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()`, as the YouTube fragment is embedded in another fragment (`RadioFragment`)

Comment: but the fragment has other parts, not just the YT player

Comment: So your YouTube fragment is embedded in RadioFragment? In that case, you need to run the code I posted inside `RadioFragment`, not your Activity, as the YouTube fragment is part of the layout for RadioFragment. Keep in mind you may need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()` too (see my update)

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `<fragment>` tag within the layout of a Fragment, it gets added as a child Fragment. This means that the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` is **not** added to the Activity's FragmentManager, but to that Fragment's `getChildFragmentManager()`.

This means that the proper way to retrieve your `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` is from within the Fragment that created it - your `RadioFragment`. Within your `RadioFragment`, you could use:

```
youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)
   getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
```

Generally, your Activity should never be reaching into the layout of fragments it adds, nor the child fragments created within. Instead, you'd want your `RadioFragment` to manage the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` it creates directly and not involve the Activity at all.

Comment: thank you for your advice and explanation, i will try it!

Comment: In what method are you calling it in? It has to be *after* `onCreateView` (since that's what inflates the layout), so generally that'd be something you'd do in `onViewCreated()`

Comment: Thank you very much! Once i put my code in onViewCreated() it worked!