# How to make YoutubeBaseActivity() support AutoResizingTextView

Tags: android, android-studio

```
class TestActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity() {
    }

class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    }

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieNameAndYear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="Gravity (2016)"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            />
```

The text view works fine when the class is `AppCompatActivity` but when it's a `YoutubeBaseActivity` it doesn't work, how do I fix it?

Comment: In the `AppCompatActivity`, the `<TextView>` is being automagically replaced with an `AppCompatTextView`, which will correctly recognize and use those attributes with the `app` prefix. The `YouTubeBaseActivity` isn't doing that substitution, and the regular `TextView` just ignores those attributes. It's possible that you could simply specify `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>` tags instead, but there might be other minor adjustments necessary, depending on the theming and such in the `YouTubeBaseActivity`.

Comment: Also, I've never really used the YouTube API, but I'm pretty sure `YouTubeBaseActivity` is rather ancient. I think there's still at least a support `Fragment` that you could put into an `AppCompatActivity` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584288. Not 100% certain. Just a heads up.

Comment: Hey, My friend, you're a genius